# Update in PyMongo with "." in key

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have to find the value of attribute "8.jpg" in collection with "job_id":"0". I have written the following query. "8.jpg" is an Object type.
`db.collection.findOne({"job_id":"0"})."8.jpg"`

I am getting following error:
`2020-10-11T23:18:39.812+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing name after . operator @(shell):1:42`

Also how to find the type of an attribute?

I am also trying to update a key in attribute "8.jpg"
`db.collection.update({"job_id": "0"},{ $set:{"8.jpg.name":"abc"}})` 
but this is coming all wrong

Answer (score 2):

You getting this error because you are doing `."8.jpg"`. you can not have a string after a dot operator.

You can try this:

```
db.collection.findOne({"job_id":"0"})["8.jpg"]
```

Comment: But this will treat jpg as attribute of 8. But that's not the case. "8.jpg" is a key name

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you see if that works?

Comment: Yes, this works. ThankYou!!
And can you tell how to update if "8.jpg" is a dict type?
Have to update a key of "8.jpg".

Comment: You can try `.update({"8.jpg" : value},{$set : {}}) `

Comment: Please mark it as accepted answer if it helped you, it will help others, and it motivates me as well!